# Mysql database-design optimal solution required

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

My questions comes first, then I'll describe the whole situation and current solution:

```
Questions.
1. Why could mySQL make enormously lots of continous read|write (300-1000 megaBytes) disk operations?
2. Is DB structure optimal (need advice otherwise)?
3. Do UniqueKey could slow down DB?
4. What could be better solution for the situation?
5. At the end vServer is getting down and I got mail with ~'ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect (2)'; So maybe issue is not in DB structure but it is some misconfiguration?
```

Situation.
    Users on the end devices are playing and when gameover comes they are storing game records in central DB. Users could see highscores table sorted by hignscore.
I cant say that there are a lot of users. Lets assume that 1 user per 1 min.

Solution.
LAMP.
Since there are several similar games that users are playing there are several similar tables+views pairs in DB. (~25 Tables+25 Views total). Most of tables contain ~30 000 records. 3 of them contain up to 150 000 records.

In order to store users uniquely: 1user-1record I made a unique key UNIQUE INDEX userid (userid, gamename, gametype, recordvalue).

Since user should see sorted values (highscores) I made a view for a table that shows what is needed. So the external php script is working with view rather then with table.

```
CREATE TABLE supergameN (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
gamename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
gametype VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'empty',
recordvalue INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE INDEX userid (userid, gamename, gametype, recordvalue)
)

CREATE VIEW supergameN_view AS
SELECT 
    id,
    userid,
    username,
    gamename,
    gametype,
    description,
    recordvalue 
FROM supergameN
ORDER BY gametype, recordvalue DESC
```

Thanks in advance. Alex.

Comment: Need data about storage engine / record count and some querys and explains. 150 000 should be easy for mysql

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the solution but something I noticed:

Leave out the `recordvalue` from the unique key, since otherwise you *would* allow several records to exist for each `userid-gamename-gametype` combination, as long asd they have different `recordvalue`s!

By using

```
UNIQUE INDEX userid (userid, gamename, gametype)
```

You ensure that per game and user you only ever store *one result*.

And, some further remarks/questions:

- Do you really need two columns to identify the game?
- What is kept in `description`: is it user or game related?

Maybe you could normalize a bit by having just a `gameid` column in your main table and (assuming that description refers to the game) a separate table `games` with columns `gameid, gamename,gametype`and `description`. And then, of course, there would be no need to keep `id` anymore, instead you would have the combination of `(userid,gameid)` as your primary key.

Comment: +! for normalization.  The first steps to optimization should be normalization.